# Vim doesn't take indent correctly my C/C++ files

Tags: c++, vim, configuration

I'm really puzzled on that one and would appreciate a quick help as I've been trying to solve this since yesterday. I've watched the videos related to indentation in vim and it works fine with my Python files. But somehow, vim ignores parameters of my vimrc file when it comes to .cpp files.

I have it configured that way in my _vimrc file under Windows.

```
" Add proper C/C++ indentation
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.c, *.cpp, *.h
    \ set tabstop=4 | 
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix

" Add proper PEP8 indentation
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4 | 
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=79 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix
```

This configuration works fine for my Python files, but automatically indents 8 characters when I create or open a C/C++ file.

Any idea of what's wrong here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use `:verbose set tabstop? softtabstop? shiftwidth?` to see where it was last set.

Comment: This is very interesting and informative. I didn't know this verbose command. It confirms it picks up correctly the configuration in my _vimrc. I don't know why it was behaving like that before. It seems to work fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You should really consider Filetype autocommands or ftplugins. I’ve written extensively about them on [vi.se]: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22256/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15329/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604

Comment: Thanks Ben. I had autocommands already. I thought the problem was solved but it happened again today. I can't explain why :( I really don't get it. I did follow your advice and read the documentation on ftplugins. I moved my c++ and python config to vimfiles\after\ftplugin\python.vim and cpp.vim and now it seems to work fine. I do have proper indentation when I code in c++.